# Undo a transaction to a wrong adress

Tags: revert-transaction

I made a transaction to a wrong adress. How can I find where the transaction reciever has an exchange adress?
Transaction:
Completed   BTC 0.10951991  2021-01-02 23:25:18 Adres:1L5wSMgerhHg8GZGcsNmAx5EXMRXSKR3He
Txid:
4a22a54a7a314a4a6fcf14d1b8a64cbc320fcd854d5cd806a23024f446a4fbb2

Comment: Bitcoin transactions cannot be reversed. The address you sent money to has never sent any money away, so the address might even be owned by no-one

Answer (score 3):

> **Undo a transaction to a wrong adress**

Bitcoin transactions cannot be undone.

> **I made a transaction to a wrong adress.**

That is usually hard to do because standard addresses have checksums.

If you sent it to a genuine address given to you by someone other than the intended recipient, you'll need to contact the person who gave you that address and see if they are willing to create a new transaction sending money to you.

If you somehow entered an address that no-one gave you, then there will almost certainly be no-one who owns that address. There are an incredibly vast number of valid addresses and almost none of them will ever be owned.

> **How can I find where the transaction reciever has an exchange adress?**

Not all addresses in use are related to exchanges. Many addresses that are in use will have been generated by standalone wallets on phones or personal computers. As I wrote above, almost all valid addresses are not owned by anyone and never will be.

There are businesses that [analyse the blockchain](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+analysis) to try to associate used addresses with exchanges but they may be very expensive to employ. Even if you did identify an exchange, the exchange has no reason to violate their customer's privacy. At best they might pass on a request to their customer for that customer to consider your request that the customer send money back to you. But even that might take an enormous amount of persuasion.

Answer (score 0):

If it was unconfirmed, you could double-spend to reverse it. Publishing a second transaction to yourself that spends bitcoin used in the first transaction.

It's talked about in this question: [Is it possible to cancel an unconfirmed transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4514/is-it-possible-to-cancel-an-unconfirmed-transaction)

Otherwise, no way to reverse it if it has been confirmed. If you can track down the owner (if it has one), you could ask for it back.